# Generic method in non generic class

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to understand how does it work when you have a non generic class, but I do have a method that accepts generic types. It's following the oracle java [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/boundedTypeParams.html) on generics.

```
public class Box<T> {

    private T obj;

    public Box (T t) { this.obj = t; }

    public T get() { return obj; }
    public void set(T obj) { this.obj = obj; }
}
```

Followed by:

```
public Class Util {

    public static void compareTest() {

        List<Box<Integer>> anArray = new ArrayList<>();
        anArray.add(new Box<Integer>(new Integer(3)));
        anArray.add(new Box<Integer>(new Integer(4)));
        anArray.add(new Box<Integer>(new Integer(5)));

        this.compare(Arrays.asList(anArray), new Box<Integer>(4));

    }

    private static <T> void compare(T[] anArray, T element) {

    }

}
```

From my understanding, because the class is not generic (not `Util<T>`), the method doesn't necessarily know what this `<T>` is, and I don't know how to tell it explicitly.

First time I tried to pass:

```
this.compare(anArray, new Box<Integer>(4));
```

But it complained about both parameters. I realized that `anArray` wasn't a box list, so I used `Arrays.asList(..)`, and now it doesn't complain about the first variable. It still does complain about Box not being of type T.

I have no idea why the first variable is being accepted, and the second is not. I also have no idea how I should have done this, properly. How do I tell the method what type to expect?

Comment: The first parameter is an array, not a list.

Comment: A list is not an array.

Comment: Try `compare(anArray.toArray(), new Box<Integer>(4));`.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon that is correct. If you want, write it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to pass a `List` as an array. You need to convert the list to an array before calling.

change

```
this.compare(Arrays.asList(anArray), new Box<Integer>(4));
```

to

```
this.compare(anArray.toArray(), new Box<Integer>(4));
```

but you really should either rename the variable `anArray` to perhaps `aList` or, better still, create the array correctly.